# '\r\n' read from configuration file is not equivalent to python's interpretation or '\r\n'

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to use a .json configuration file to dictate how I should write to my CSV.

The CSV dict within my json file reads as follows:

```
"CSV": {
        "Delimiter": ",",
        "Quotechar": "\"",
        "Quoting": "csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL",
        "LineTerminator": "\\r\\n"
    },
```

I want to use '\r\n' as my lineterminator field in my csv.Dictwriter statement:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=search_results[0].keys(), delimiter=config['CSV']['Delimiter'],
                            quotechar=config['CSV']['Quotechar'], quoting=quoting, lineterminator=config['CSV']['LineTerminator'])
```

The issue is when I pull the LineTerminator field, it is not equivalent to Python's interpretation of '\r\n' and I'm unable to generate my CSV properly:

```
a= config['CSV']['LineTerminator']
    print(a)
    print(repr(a))
    print(repr('\r\n'))
 if '\r\n' == a:
        print('Equivalent')
```

```
Output:
\r\n
'\\r\\n'
'\r\n'
```

I've tried to use the replace() method to no avail.

Comment: How did you try replace? `a = a.replace('\\r', '\r')` (and the same for `\n`) should work.

Comment: I tried to do a.replace('\\\\', '\\') because of the escape characters. I tried your method and it worked! Thank you very much!

I'm trying to understand why you can't just replace the escaped characters. Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a double backslash means a literal backslash, `"\\r\\n"` literally means a backslash followed by a letter `r`, followed by another backslash followed by a letter `n`.

You should use `"\r\n"` to denote a carriage return followed by a newline character in your JSON configuration file:

```
"LineTerminator": "\r\n"
```

Comment: Newline characters are not allowed in JSON strings, which is why you have to use the escape sequence `"\n"` to denote a newline character.

Comment: This also works when I update my configuration file. I was under the impression that  I had to use a backslash to escape the backslash in the JSON file (\ + \r); however, I must have been wrong. Thanks for the help